# Mapping past the antimeridian line... (in ggmap/ggplot2)

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, plot, coordinates

I'm trying to map the locations of a certain plant species on the extended northwestern Hawaiian islands. I'm using ggplot2 and ggmap but only longitudinal coordinates between -180° and 180° are allowed. How can I extend the map beyond the -180° mark to -185° (which would be 175° E)?

Alternatively, is it possible to shift the center of the map from the meridian line (0°) to the antimeridian line (-180°/180°)?

**My code:**

```
baseArchipelago = get_map(location=c(-185,7,-154.5,29.3), zoom=6, maptype="terrain",)

mapArchipelago<-ggmap(baseArchipelago)
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KIHw.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
baseArchipelago = get_map(location=c(-160, 19), zoom=4, maptype="terrain")
ggmap(baseArchipelago) + 
coord_fixed(xlim = c(-155, -185), ylim=c(30, 10), ratio=1/cos(pi*19/180))
```

Here, I'm creating quite a large base map, and then using `coord_fixed` to zoom in (going past the antimeridian, while keeping Hawaii in the view). The `ratio=1/cos(pi*19/180)` requires the `lat` coordinate (19). See Pere's response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915118/ggmap-changing-size-of-map) for more info.

[image: hawaiiMap]

Comment: Yes, should be baseArchipelago. My mistake. I used 4 coordinates (not 3) for the corners of the map. Your method did not work. It extended the map beyond -180 like I did before but that region still only a grid, no map (see the image link I posted)

Comment: Interesting. Are you using the Google Maps API?